# What is the best way to prevent IE from Caching Ajax Calls?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, caching

I was working on an MVC 5/Jquery project and we encountered an issue on IE 10/11. Internet explorer is caching succeeding ajax calls.

We solved this problem by

**disabling cache on every jQuery ajax calls:**

$.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false,
                headers: {
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
                    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'Expires': '0'
                }
            });

**disabling caching on the server side/Controller:**

```
    // GetFolderDetails is the Action being called through ajax.
    public ActionResult GetFolderDetails(long folderId)
    {
        // Code Here...

        TurnOffResponseCaching();
        return PartialView(PartialView_FolderDetails, selectedFolder);
    }
    private void TurnOffResponseCaching()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(System.Web.HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    }
```

Both of this solutions solved the problem.

Between the two, what is the best way to disable caching on every ajax calls?

Comment: I would choose the server side. We tried it and it seems the client side does not work in every case. It also seems logical to mark the response as no-cache, not the request. However, using an attribute would (either `OutputCacheAttribute` or your own) be preferable over modifying the `Response` directly in the controller.

I have also marked the question as inconclusive since it may depend on the situation.